# Remove duplicate line with random starts php

Tags: php, duplicates

I have a file containing data something like this:

```
randomString-data1
randomString-data2
randomString-data4
randomString-data2
randomString-data2
randomString-data3
randomString-data4
```

The output I want:

```
randomString-data1
randomString-data2
randomString-data4
randomString-data3
```

The length of random string is between 20 to 25 characters. The randomString is not important. The data after it is of relevance only. What could be the best way to remove such duplicates?

All I can think of is the brute force way to explode each line at "-" and compare with all others. But is there a better way?

**Note: The random strings are important. But it is okay if any one of the randomString remains from the duplicate entries.**

Comment: Explode and check

Comment: Well I did mention in the question that, explode and check is all I can think of. I want a better way if possible. Because the file is big.

Comment: well, instead of brute-force-comparing, you could sort it first, so you only have to compare each entry with the neighbouring. or use some predefined function you can read about in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php)? the question, however, would be as to why there are random strings in front, if they are not important in the first place?

Comment: I would explode, but then asign the values to a new array, setting the 'data' part as index, and the randomString as value. This will automatically prevent duplicates from being added. This means you will only keep the last value of 'data-randomstring' combination, not sure that would work for you.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann The random strings are important. But it is okay if any one of the randomString remains from the duplicate entries. I am not getting any clue to sort them. Could you please explain how I can sort them?

Comment: @RipHunter again, [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php) provides.

Comment: what if `randomString` contains hyphens?

Answer (score 1):

firstly explode them by '\n' then by '-'

```
$arr = explode('\n', $str);

$data = array();
foreach($arr as $val)
{
   $temp = explode("-", $val);
   $data[$temp[1]] = $temp[0];
}

$str = "";
foreach($data as $k => $v)
{
  $str .= $v . "-" . $k;
}
```

Comment: Yep. That is what I meant in my comment. I was going to add that as an answer but you already adjusted yours to do the same.

Answer (score 1):

Explode and array flip and then get array keys

```
$content_array = explode($file_contents);
//Remove duplicate entries
$flipped_array = array_flip($content_array);
file_put_contents('/path/to/file', implode("\n", array_keys($flipped_array));
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do it this way

```
<?php
$file = <<<EOF
randomString-data1
randomString-data2
randomString-data4
randomString-data2
randomString-data2
randomString-data3
randomString-data4
EOF;

$found = [];
foreach (explode("\n", $file) as $line) {
    list(, $date) = explode('-', $line);
    if (!isset($found[$date])) {
        echo "$line<br>";
        $found[$date] = true; 
    }
}
?>
```